# Cant stop the program repeating using "while" loop... Python

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x

Here's what i have so far... if you run the module and choose to play it simply repeats the dice throw infinitely. Help?

```
answer=input("Would you like to play? Answer Y/N: ")

while answer == "Y" or answer == "y" or answer == "yes": 
    import random
    die=random.randint(1,6)

    dieTwo=random.randint(1,6)    

    if die== 1:
        print("XXXXXXX")
        print("X     X")
        print("X  O  X")
        print("X     X")
        print("XXXXXXX")
        print("You rolled a one...")
    if die== 2:
        print("XXXXXXX")
        print("X   O X")
        print("X     X")
        print("X O   X")
        print("XXXXXXX")
        print("You rolled a two...")
    if die== 3:
        print("XXXXXXX")
        print("X   O X")
        print("X  O  X")
        print("X O   X")
        print("XXXXXXX")
        print("You rolled a three...")
    if die== 4:
        print("XXXXXXX")
        print("X O O X")
        print("X     X")
        print("X O O X")
        print("XXXXXXX")
        print("You rolled a four...")
    if die== 5:
        print("XXXXXXX")
        print("X O O X")
        print("X  O  X")
        print("X O O X")
        print("XXXXXXX")
        print("You rolled a five...")
    if die== 6:
        print("XXXXXXX")
        print("X O O X")
        print("X O O X")
        print("X O O X")
        print("XXXXXXX")
        print("You rolled a six...")

    if dieTwo==1:
        print("XXXXXXX")
        print("X     X")
        print("X  O  X")
        print("X     X")
        print("XXXXXXX")
        print("and a one")
    if dieTwo==2:
        print("XXXXXXX")
        print("X   O X")
        print("X     X")
        print("X O   X")
        print("XXXXXXX")
        print("and a two")
    if dieTwo==3:
        print("XXXXXXX")
        print("X   O X")
        print("X  O  X")
        print("X O   X")
        print("XXXXXXX")
        print("and a three")
    if dieTwo==4:
        print("XXXXXXX")
        print("X O O X")
        print("X     X")
        print("X O O X")
        print("XXXXXXX")
        print("and a four")
    if dieTwo==5:
        print("XXXXXXX")
        print("X O O X")
        print("X  O  X")
        print("X O O X")
        print("XXXXXXX")
        print("and a five")
    if dieTwo==6:
        print("XXXXXXX")
        print("X O O X")
        print("X O O X")
        print("X O O X")
        print("XXXXXXX")
        print("and a six")
print("")

if answer=="N" or answer=="n" or answer=="no":
    print("Thank you for playing.")
```

Comment: Yes, and that perfectly what you programmed it for... You probably want to move your answer=input(...) within your while loop that would also require an initial condition like answer='Y'.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you expect this to be anything but an infinite loop? You have a `while` loop that checks for your condition, and this condition will always be true because you never change `answer`

You could also make a function for printing your dice, and instead of using `or` you can use `answer in ("Y", "y", "yes")` as one example if you wanted to be terser in places where you have conditions like this.

Answer (score 0):

As you are taking the input `answer` only once from the user, its value remains the same during the entire execution of the program.
Thus the `while` predicate always evaluates to `True` if you pass `'Y'` or `'y'` or `'yes'`.

I would suggest you take input each time you iterate.
Something like this might help:

```
while 1:

answer=input("Would you like to play? Answer Y/N: ")
if answer in ('Y', 'y', 'yes'):
# play the game
else:
# stop the game
```

Another suggestion: **Do not import inside the loop.**
Try to put all your import statements at the top of your script.

Happy Coding !